# String Comparision in if condition always errors

Tags: java, if-statement, comparison

This looks like the simplest of all the codes and yet, it is uncompilable. I am completely frustrated with this. Please help.

here is what I'm doing - I break a string of words into Array of Strings. I then further split the string in the 2nd index of the array and do my compariso (only if is of length 16). Below are the conditions -
the first half must be all digits and greater than zero.
the second half must equal to "-default" (non-case sensitive).

for some reason, the if condition is always unacceptable for 2nd half comparison.

```
if (linearray[2].length() == 16) {
        String first8 = linearray[2].substring(0, 7);
        String last8 = linearray[2].substring(8, 15);
        String value = "-default";      
        try {
            int isNum = Integer.parseInt(first8);
            if (isNum > 0) {
                return "Correct";
            } else {
                return "Incorrect";
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return "Incorrect";
        }
        //---------------HERE IS THE ISSUE--------------
        if (last8.equals(value)) {

        }
    }
```

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Comment: Did you try debugging the program? Can you provide some sample input?

Comment: You should not change your code because these answer would seem not valid. If you changed your code and it is still not working, you should ask another question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Thank you guys! Here is the code -

```
if (linearray[2].length() == 16) {
        String first8 = linearray[2].substring(0, 7);
        String last8 = linearray[2].substring(8, 15);
        String value = "-default";      
        try {
            int isNum = Integer.parseInt(first8);
            if (isNum > 0) {
                if (last8.endsWith(value)) {
                    return "Correct";
                } else {
                    return "Incorrect";
                }
            } else {
                return "Incorrect";
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return "Incorrect";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

```
    if (linearray[2].endsWith("default")) {

    }
```

doesn't pass compilation since it's unreachable code. Your method will always return (or throw an exception) before reaching it, since the `try-catch` block that precedes it always returns something, and if an exception other than `NumberFormatException` is thrown, this code still won't be reached.

Therefore there's no point in having this condition.

Hmm, you changed the code in the question, but the new condition

```
    if (last8.equals(value)) {

    }
```

has the same issue as the previous one.

Comment: What if a non NumberFormatException exception is thrown? probably won't but is possible

Comment: @giorashc, then the exception will be thrown upwards and still not reach the code.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that you have defined a flow which doesn't returns anything, but the method is expected to return a String.

```
 if (last8.equals(value)) {

        }
```

However, the above code is unreachable. The flow returns before it comes here. What are you trying to achieve?
Move this code to a more reachable position, e.g. before the return statements or inside

```
if (isNum > 0) {
                return "Correct";
            }
```

this condition.